# Can you water bath a cooked then cooled jam recipe?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, canning, jam

I tried a peach jam recipe that is cooked then cooled to thicken without pectin (6+ hour cool time). The recipe says you can freeze it or can it. What would be the safest method to can it? I have always used the water bath method while the jam was still hot. Would you put the cooled jam in sanitized jars, seal and band them, then place in a 'cool' water bath bringing it up to boiling? Would you then process for 10 minutes like usual?
BTW...the jam is the perfect consistency. Would heating it change that? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  While theoretically you could can the jam using some kind of very-slow-heating of the jars in a water bath, in practice I can't find any canning authority who thinks that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may can it, but you will need to bring it to a boil again.

From [The University of Georgia for the National Center for Home Food Preservation](https://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/uga/2019_ProcessingJJ.pdf)

> Because we are interested in recommending jam and jelly making procedures that offer
> the highest quality, the least health and safety risks, and the lowest chance of losing product, all
> Extension recommendations for jams and jellies include a boiling water canning process for
> room temperature storage of sealed jars. Standard canning jars used with self-sealing lids and
> ring bands, pre-sterilization of clean canning jars, **hot filling of product into the jars,** and
> processing for 5 minutes in a boiling water canner are recommended for highest quality and to
> prevent mold growth.

Emphasis mine.

Please consult a reputable canning source for processing times for your situation and altitude.

The consistency may change, but I don't think it would be drastically different.